# Pandas - fill a table based on another table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've two tables :

- df1 is empty with columns = {'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', C', 'A'} and 62 rows.
- df2 is not empty with columns = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'} and 62 rows.

I would like to fill df1 rows with df2 rows based on column name (note that df1 and df2 are just for the example, my tables have more than 3,000 columns).

I'm currently using the following code:

```
for col in df1:
     if col in df2:
          df1[col] = df2[col]
```

**So I was wondering, is it possible to do that without looping through columns ? As it would be done with a pd.merge or pd.concat.**
I think that looping through columns is increasing my running time a lot when df1 has a lot of columns.

I've also tried using merge or update but as I've duplicate column names in df1 it seems not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does df1 has few columns with the same name?

Comment: because df1's columns are assets contained in df1, df1 can have multiple time the same asset. df2 contains asset prices so I want to fill prices in df1

Comment: Honestly, I do recommend using columns with unique names. Even for humans thats hard to understand and with 3000+ columns you can not check if your logic works without mistakes. 
Have you considered MultIndex as columns? Like [(Asset, No1)(Asset, No2)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `reindex` and `update` for **in place** modification:

```
df1.update(df2.reindex(df1.columns, axis=1))
```

example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A'],
                   index=range(4))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(24).reshape(4,6),
                   columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])

df1.update(df2.reindex(df1.columns, axis=1))

print(df1)
```

output:

```
    A   B   A   C   C   A
0   0   1   0   2   2   0
1   6   7   6   8   8   6
2  12  13  12  14  14  12
3  18  19  18  20  20  18
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the columns in df2 exist in df1, you better do:

```
for col in df2.columns:
    if (col in df1.columns):
         df1[col] = df2[col]
```

This would be much quicker then your code with nested loops.

Comment: It can happen that col doesn't exist in df2 so I let it empty that's why I used that if confition

Comment: @OnealR - I have edited the answer with an 'if'. Still without nested loops